# How to generate random variables and sum all them in python

Tags: python, random, sum

My problem explicitly is

```
Z=sum_(i)^12 (x_i).
```

where i is indices and x_i's are random number...

I need an explicit code in Python to produce 12 random variables and sum all them.

I tried write code using if, while loop, but I could not get it.

I need your help...

Comment: Passing thought: assuming a perfectly fair random, isn't that the same as: `12 * a_single_random_nubmer`? But ... the formula in the post is confusing and looks off from the English description.

Comment: You sure you do not need to subtract 6 from that to get a normal distribution?

Comment: since I will extend it to more realizations, I think I need write a code this way, but I am not sure.

Comment: The second part of the question is to suggest an approximation for the distribution of z and its parameters,  but the first I need to code the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to use arbitrary variable just structure it as a function.
You can structure it similar to l82Munch, but this may be more readable for you since your just starting. Note that range is a generator function that returns a list up to the last call. So range(1,3) returns [1,2]

```
import random
def rand_sum(i, j):    
    sum_list = []
    for rand_num in range(i, j+1):
        sum_list.append(random.random()) # Check random docs for a function that returns
    return sum(sum_list)                 # a different set of randoms if this isn't 
                                         # appropriate
```

Comment: When I print sum_list, Python shows a bunch of numbers, while I expect only 12. could you tell me the reason?

Comment: sum_list is the container for the random numbers and it is then summed, perhaps it would be more aptly named tobesummed_list. Either assign rand_sum(i, j) to a different variable and print that or print rand_sum(i,j) directly.

Comment: Ok, I see. The program adds each random variable to the list after it produces successively. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
rand_sum = sum( random.random() for x in range(12) )
```

See the [random documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But, is there any way coding for arbitrary range like packet so that I can change the number of variables? I am new in programming. And I already know how to write code for direct calculation like above, but I want to make definition like, rand_sum(i, j) where i is "start" and j is "stop".

Answer (score 0):

In probabilistic modelling, you can define distributions then sum them.

Personally, I use [OpenTURNS](http://openturns.org) platform for that.

```
import openturns as ot

x1 = ot.Normal(0, 2)  # Normal distribution mean = 0, std = 2
x2 = ot.Uniform(3, 5) # Uniform distribution between 3 and 5

sum = x1 + x2
```

That's it.

If x1,..., x12 are 12 distributions identically distributed you can write:

```
sum_12 = sum([x1] * 12)
```